# asp.net ajax popupextender aligment issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup, modalpopupextender

I have used the ajax popup in my application where one link opens a popup and from the popup, there is another popupextender that gets opened. This popup is not center aligned. Is there any way i can align this popup to the center of the screen. Note that the first popup is center aligned but second one is not.

Answer (score 0):

are you hiding the first popup when showing another one?, if not, use client side scripts to do so and i think that will solve your problem.

you can see good example here - http://beta.firstphera.com/GiftRegistry/ProductDetails.aspx?pcid=23

just click on any product image, enter quantity and click on add to registry

Comment: I am not hiding the parent popup.